# Authentication for different applications with the same encrypted password

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, encryption, devise

If I have to use the table for my application, for another application (android), how would I decrypt the password for authentication into that application, or how would I integrate what Devise Encryption for Ruby created into a different authentication system? Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about setting up an API in your Rails app for authentication?  Your android app can accept the login/password and POST them back to the application.